# table back-up either in CSV or SQL Format incomplete

Tags: php, mysql, backup

I have that script that downloads all the contents of my table in sql format and save a local copy. My problem is the content of my table is so huge, the actual data is about 50MB and the data being generated of my script is just 3.5MB. What's wrong with my script? why  all data are not written in sql file?

```
$table = "Downloads";

$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
$num_fields = $db->num_fields($result);

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
        for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
        {   
            $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
            $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
            if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
            if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
        }
        $return.= ");\n";
    }
}
$return.="\n\n\n";

//save file
$handle = fopen(UPLOAD_XML_PATH_ABSOLUTE.'downloads_backup'.'.sql','w+');
if(fwrite($handle,$return)){
    fclose($handle);
    //$ret = true;
} else {
    //$ret = false;
}
```

Comment: seems to be a question missing here

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but one small note: Why do you store all these values in a variable in the first place and not just write them directly to the file? Doesn't make any sense to me, because you only get your available memory filled up.

**Update**

A couple more notes: Maybe mysql_real_escape_string() should be used and why do repeat all those INSERTS? One INSERT followed by many (),(); should be enough. How do you differentiate between integer, string, boolean and NULL in your code? This could lead to a problem if you try to use your sql file later.

Comment: so the script above filled up the memory that's why the content being saved is incomplete? And also i didn't use differentiation of data types.

Comment: Not necessarily and in your particular case, probably not. However if you set your memory limit to 64MB and are already holding a 50MB string in memory, it's certainly getting tight. Another thing that could be a problem is time. Have you checked that your script has enough time to finish and not getting any timeouts? Did you get any errors at all? Is anything after fwrite executed? How many bytes are written by fwrite (return value)? The thing with the data types was just a suggestion...

Comment: So how can i reduce the use of memory? I compute the memory usage it's about 50MB on 30MB of return value for about 46,000 records.

Comment: Still working on the problem? Hm. As suggested in the beginning instead of storing the value in the variable "$return" just directly output everything by using fwrite/echo. Eg.: fwrite($handle, '"'.$row[$j].'"');.. Assure that the file handle opining is set accordingly at the beginning!

Comment: Yes still working on that.Actually i change my code because the fields from source table is different from destination table. What i did is I just get the fields that i am needed and add some values to match on new insert. And also, any idea how to insert an auto increment value?

Answer (score 0):

Filesize might not be the best way to determine whether the script is working properly. Have you checked over the data the script produces?

1. Use the saved sql file to create
   a temp duplicate of the table you
   are trying to export.
2. Run your script on this temp table.
3. Use a utility such as [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to see
   if the two files are identical or
   not.

It's not terribly elegant, but it is quick, doesn't require any costly tools, and if WinMerge does pickup any differences between the two, that should also indicate where the problem lies.

Comment: Yes I checked the data and it's just 1/8 of actual content.